# uploading a simple collection for pivotviewer

Tags: parsing, collections, pivotviewer

Hey I am creating a demo to display the benefits of using a pivotviewer.  I created a simple collection with about 50 items to display, and created a simple pivotviewer to display it.

here is my pivotviewer sitting inside of main.xaml

```
<Pivot:PivotViewer x:Name="PivotViewer" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

And my code behind is like this

```
Public Inventory()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  PivotViewer.LoadCollection("http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Titles?$select=AverageRating,ReleaseYear,Rating", string.Empty);
}
```

This isn't my collection but my pivotviewer does the exact same with this collection.
When I load the collection it displays the URL in the upper left and the loading icon.  After it finishes it doesn't load the collection.

I'm pretty sure its not my collection because of the fact that it doesn't load the netflix collection, but I've checked my collection and loaded it in the microsoft live labs pivot, loaded it into my server, set the MIME types for CXML/DZC/DZI as text/xml.

I've read a few other people who are asking similar questions, and I think the fiddler2 suggestion would work but I have a deadline rapidly approaching and I don't think I have enough time to learn how to use fiddler.

Is there any more options I should check or can someone give me a crash course in fiddler testing?  Any help would be great, and detail would be greatly appreciated because I'm repetitively new to this and kinda short on time, thanks

EDIT: I've implemented an error message and it says:

ParsingError

Error parsinghttp://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Titles?$select=AverageRating,ReleaseYear,Rating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PivotViewer verifies the Uri before it processes it.  It is fairly tough on what it will allow.  I've had to implement pass-thru's before to get it to work.

In my case it was used to pass several query string values that were causing the problem.  I resolved it by passing a simple key and parsing data out that way.  In your case, and since this is for a demo, I would simply create a local page that does nothing more than return the results from your netflix query.

Hope this helps.

Tony

Comment: Hey @Tony, thanks for the reply.  I ended up doing as you said and created a page just to display the pivotviewer, after all it was only a demo to showing off the benefits of using a pivotviewer.